# Snazzy maps not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I have been practising with gmaps with snazzy maps for custimization for my site and unable to get the javascript correct. Can anyone lend a hand, i know i am close https://jsfiddle.net/t78kgeaw/

**HTML**

```
<div id="maps">

</div>
```

**JS**

```
// Create and Initialise the Map (required) our google map below

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

        function init() {
            // Basic options for a simple Google Map
            // For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions

    var mapOptions = {

         // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)

                zoom: 17,
                scrollwheel: false,
                // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)

                center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.088530, -64.367951), // Nova Scotia

                // How you would like to style the map. 
                // This is where you would paste any style found on [Snazzy Maps][1].
                // copy the Styles from Snazzy maps,  and paste that style info after the word "styles:"

                styles: [
{
    "featureType": "all",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "hue": "#ff4400"
        },
        {
            "saturation": -68
        },
        {
            "lightness": -4
        },
        {
            "gamma": 0.72
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "gamma": 3.1
        },
        {
            "color": "#ffffff"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": "-12"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#269793"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#972663"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#972663"
        },
        {
            "lightness": "13"
        },
        {
            "gamma": "1.99"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#972663"
        },
        {
            "visibility": "on"
        },
        {
            "saturation": "83"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "transit",
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -64
        },
        {
            "lightness": 16
        },
        {
            "gamma": 0.47
        },
        {
            "weight": 2.7
        },
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "transit.line",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "lightness": -48
        },
        {
            "gamma": 1.2
        },
        {
            "saturation": -23
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "gamma": 0.44
        },
        {
            "saturation": -33
        },
        {
            "color": "#266397"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "gamma": 0.77
        },
        {
            "saturation": 65
        },
        {
            "lightness": 99
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "gamma": 0.11
        },
        {
            "weight": 5.6
        },
        {
            "saturation": 99
        },
        {
            "lightness": -86
        }
    ]
}
]



    var mapElement = document.getElementById('maps');

            // Create the Google Map using out element and options defined above
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

    // Following section, you can create your info window content using html markup

            var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                '</div>'+
                '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
                '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
                'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
                'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
                'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
                '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
                'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
                'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
                'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
                'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
                'Heritage Site.</p>'+
                '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
                'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
                '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>';


    // Define the image to use for the map marker (58 x 44 px)

            var image = 'http://uploads.webflow.com/537f700d5bb0a27f34444d0c/53b054015eb95f024f4d7c5e_map_marker.png';

    // Define the Lattitude and Longitude for the map location

            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.088530, -64.367951);

    // Define the map marker characteristics

            var mapMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            title:  'Frostbyte Interactive'

            });

           // Following Lines are needed if you use the Info Window to display content when map marker is clicked

       var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: contentString
                    });

        // Following line turns the marker, into a clickable button and when clicked, opens the info window

            google.maps.event.addListener(mapMarker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map, mapMarker);
            });
```

}

**CSS**

```
  #maps img {  
   width: 500px;
   max-width: none;
```

}

Comment: I think you have a missing closing parenthesis after initialization of mapOptions variable.

Comment: I get a javascript error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Working for me.

HTML:

```
<div id="maps">

 </div>
```

JS:

```
 // Create and Initialise the Map (required) our google map below

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

            function init() {
                // Basic options for a simple Google Map
                // For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions

                var mapOptions = {

                    // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)

                    zoom: 17,
                    scrollwheel: false,
                    // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)

                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.088530, -64.367951), // Nova Scotia

                    // How you would like to style the map.
                    // This is where you would paste any style found on [Snazzy Maps][1].
                    // copy the Styles from Snazzy maps,  and paste that style info after the word "styles:"

                    styles: [
                        {
                            "featureType": "all",
                            "elementType": "geometry",
                            "stylers": [
                                {
                                    "hue": "#ff4400"
                                },
                                {
                                    "saturation": -68
                                },
                                {
                                    "lightness": -4
                                },
                                {
                                    "gamma": 0.72
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
                            "elementType": "geometry",
                            "stylers": [
                                {
                                    "gamma": 3.1
                                },
                                {
                                    "color": "#ffffff"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "featureType": "poi.park",
                            "elementType": "all",
                            "stylers": [
                                {
                                    "saturation": "-12"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "featureType": "poi.park",
                            "elementType": "geometry.fill",
                            "stylers": [
                                {
                                    "color": "#269793"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "featureType": "road.highway",
                            "elementType": "geometry.fill",
                            "stylers": [
                                {
                                    "color": "#972663"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "featureType": "road.arterial",
                            "elementType": "geometry.fill",
                            "stylers": [
                                {
                                    "color": "#972663"
                                },
                                {
                                    "lightness": "13"
                                },
                                {
                                    "gamma": "1.99"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "featureType": "road.local",
                            "elementType": "geometry.fill",
                            "stylers": [
                                {
                                    "color": "#972663"
                                },
                                {
                                    "visibility": "on"
                                },
                                {
                                    "saturation": "83"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "featureType": "transit",
                            "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
                            "stylers": [
                                {
                                    "saturation": -64
                                },
                                {
                                    "lightness": 16
                                },
                                {
                                    "gamma": 0.47
                                },
                                {
                                    "weight": 2.7
                                },
                                {
                                    "visibility": "off"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "featureType": "transit.line",
                            "elementType": "geometry",
                            "stylers": [
                                {
                                    "lightness": -48
                                },
                                {
                                    "gamma": 1.2
                                },
                                {
                                    "saturation": -23
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "featureType": "water",
                            "elementType": "all",
                            "stylers": [
                                {
                                    "gamma": 0.44
                                },
                                {
                                    "saturation": -33
                                },
                                {
                                    "color": "#266397"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "featureType": "water",
                            "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                            "stylers": [
                                {
                                    "gamma": 0.77
                                },
                                {
                                    "saturation": 65
                                },
                                {
                                    "lightness": 99
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "featureType": "water",
                            "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
                            "stylers": [
                                {
                                    "gamma": 0.11
                                },
                                {
                                    "weight": 5.6
                                },
                                {
                                    "saturation": 99
                                },
                                {
                                    "lightness": -86
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                };


                var mapElement = document.getElementById('maps');

                // Create the Google Map using out element and options defined above
                var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

                // Following section, you can create your info window content using html markup

                var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
                        '<div id="siteNotice">' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>' +
                        '<div id="bodyContent">' +
                        '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
                        'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the ' +
                        'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) ' +
                        'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km ' +
                        '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major ' +
                        'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is ' +
                        'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the ' +
                        'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, ' +
                        'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World ' +
                        'Heritage Site.</p>' +
                        '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">' +
                        'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> ' +
                        '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>';


                // Define the image to use for the map marker (58 x 44 px)

                var image = 'http://uploads.webflow.com/537f700d5bb0a27f34444d0c/53b054015eb95f024f4d7c5e_map_marker.png';

                // Define the Lattitude and Longitude for the map location

                var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.088530, -64.367951);

                // Define the map marker characteristics

                var mapMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    icon: image,
                    title: 'Frostbyte Interactive'

                });

                // Following Lines are needed if you use the Info Window to display content when map marker is clicked

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: contentString
                });

                // Following line turns the marker, into a clickable button and when clicked, opens the info window

                google.maps.event.addListener(mapMarker, 'click', function () {
                    infowindow.open(map, mapMarker);
                });

            }
```

CSS:

```
#maps {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
```